# Two-dimensional int array is not accepting the dimensions I am providing

Tags: java, arrays

This is the code that is in my `GridGenerator` class. The purpose is to create multiple rectangular rooms that can eventually be joined together into a map.

```
int xRange, yRange;

//constructor
public GridGenerator(int xInput, int yInput) {
    xRange = xInput;
    yRange = yInput;
}

int[][] grid = new int[yRange][xRange];
//the first number indicates the number of rows, the second number indicates the number of columns
//positions dictated with the origin at the upper-left corner and positive axes to bottom and left

void getPosition(int x, int y) {
    int position = grid[y][x]; //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here
    System.out.println(position);
}
```

This is the code that is in my `MapperMain` class. The purpose is to join `GridGenerator` instances into a multi-room map. I'm also using it for debugging and scaffolding purposes for now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GridGenerator physicalLayer1 = new GridGenerator(10,15);

    physicalLayer1.getPosition(0, 0); //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here

}
```

I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error. At some point, `xRange` is assigned a value of 10 and `yRange` is assigned a value of 15. However, when I attempt to use `xRange` and `yRange` as the parameters for `grid`, Java has some problem with that and I'm not sure why. If I assign values to `xRange` and `yRange` in the `GridGenerator` class, there doesn't seem to be a problem. When I use the constructor in the `MapperMain` class, I get this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
int[][] grid = new int[yRange][xRange];
```

despite being coded *after* the constructor, is executed *before* the constructor executes, and when the line executes the size variables have their default initialization values of `0`.

The reason it executes before the constructor is due to the initialization order: (among other things) All instance variables are initialized, in the order coded, *before* the constructor executes.

To fix the problem, change your code to:

```
// remove variables yRange and xRange, unless you need them for some other reason
int[][] grid;

public GridGenerator(int yRange, int xRange) {
    grid = new int[xRange][yRange];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
grid = new int[yRange][xRange];
```

should be in the constructor, since in your code sample `grid` has never been initialized with proper values of `yRange` and `xRange`.

So - your class should look something like this:

```
public class GridGenerator {
     private int xRange, yRange;
     private int[][] grid;

     //constructor
     public GridGenerator(int xInput, int yInput) {
         xRange = xInput;
         yRange = yInput;
         grid = new int[yRange][xRange]; 
     }

     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] grid = new int[yRange][xRange];
```

You must give some fixed value in the range of array and if looking for dynamic array use array list